# Can I diff streams in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Can I perform a diff between the latest versions of the files/directories (or perhaps the latest baselines) in two different streams that may reside in two different projects?

The two projects are basically branches of the same software and I need to diff the source tree between the branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [`cleartool diffbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm) in order two diff two baselines produced on those two stream.
And that will only work if there is a common ancestor found in the history of baselines of said streams.

But for the *latest* versions of a stream (as displayed by their respective associated view)... the simpler way remain to use any thirdparty diff tool ([winmerge](http://winmerge.org/), [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), ...) and diff the view contents.

Creating baselines just for a punctual comparison isn't worth the effort and the added metadata created just for that.
Two snapshot views on two streams will be enough to have a stable content (as opposed to a dynamic view whose content might change *dynamically* at any moment), and you can use any diff tools on those snapshot contents.